# How to provide elastic ip to aws eks for external service with type loadbalancer?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, elastic-ip

I am using eks 1.16. I have one service which has type Loadbalancer with internet-facing.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  name: kafka-test-3-0-external
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: kafka-0.21.5
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: kafka-broker
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kafka
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kafka-test-3
    pod: "kafka-test-3-0"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: external-broker
      port: 19092
      targetPort: 19092
      protocol: TCP
#
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: kafka-broker
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kafka
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kafka-test-3
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: "kafka-test-3-0"
```

I want to provide elastic-ip/static-ip to that external service.

**Problem:**
With Loadbalancer type, when I delete the service it will delete loadbalancer.
When I install once again then it will create new load balancer with new ip.

**Usecase:** If I will uninstall/delete that service still the IP must be same.

How can I provide elastic-ip/static-ip?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I assign a static IP to my EKS service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60095864/how-can-i-assign-a-static-ip-to-my-eks-service)

Comment: You can't as per my R&D. You can assign only elastic ip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one annotation to provide elastic-ip for network-load-balancer

**`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: eipalloc-05666791973f6a240`**

If you're using Amazon EKS 1.16 or later, you can assign Elastic IP addresses to the Network Load Balancer by adding the following annotation. Replace the  (including <>) with the Allocation IDs of your Elastic IP addresses. The number of Allocation IDs must match the number of subnets used for the load balancer.

**Note:** You can not use this annotation for the **internal load balancer**.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: "kafka-test-3-1.kafka.internal"
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: "60"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: eipalloc-022b9722973f6a222
  name: kafka-test-3-1-external
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: kafka-0.21.5
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: kafka-broker
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kafka
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kafka-test-3
    pod: "kafka-test-3-1"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: external-broker
      port: 19092
      targetPort: 19092
      protocol: TCP
#
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: kafka-broker
    app.kubernetes.io/name: kafka
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kafka-test-3
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: "kafka-test-3-1"
```

It will always use elasticIp for that loadbalancer.

For more eks annotations.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html