# Dedicated IP address to LoadBalancer mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing

We're serving our product on AWS EKS where the service is created of type `LoadBalancer`. The ELB IP is assigned by AWS and this is what is being shared to the client.

However, when we re-deploy the service when we're making some changes/improvements, the ELB IP changes. Since this is causing us to frequently send mails to all the clients, we would need a dedicated IP which needs to be mapped to LB and thus will not change with re-deployment of the service.

Any existing AWS solution or a nice pointer to solve this situation would be helpful.

Comment: Create an Elastic IP and attach to ELB. You can detach and reattach EIP when you have new ELB

Answer (score 1):

You can use elastic ip as is described here [How to provide elastic ip to aws eks for external service with type loadbalancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902641/how-to-provide-elastic-ip-to-aws-eks-for-external-service-with-type-loadbalancer), and here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/eks/latest/userguide/network-load-balancing.html, just adding an anotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: eipalloc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,eipalloc-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy` to the nlb:

`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-eip-allocations: eipalloc-05666791973f6a240`

Another way is to use a domain name (my way). Then use https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md annotations to link your Service or Ingress with a dns name and configure `external-dns` to use your dns provider like Route53.

For example:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ambassador
  namespace: ambassador
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: 'myserver.mydomain.com'
```

Every time your LoadBalancer changes the ip the dns server will be updated by the correct ip.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have better control over exposed resources, you can use Ingress Controller such as AWS Load Balancer Controller https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/

With it, you'll be able to re-use the same ALBs for multiple Kubernetes services using `alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name` annotation. It will create multiple listener rules based on Ingress configuration.

(Applicable if you're not restricted by hardcoded FW rules or similar configurations, that will require you to have static IPs, which is not recommended today)