# how to get public IP of an EKS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

```
~ kubectl get svc
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.100.0.1       <none>                                                                    443/TCP        36h
api-service   LoadBalancer   10.100.186.209   a609dda14861b4a477883069eeec1c29-1006084812.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80:30430/TCP   57m
```

instead of `a609dda14861b4a477883069eeec1c29-1006084812.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`, I need the actual IP address.

How to get it?

EDITED:

This command returned empty

```
kubectl get svc api-service -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'
```

It seems that it simply doesn't have an IP address. How come?

Comment: Can you use a tool like `dig` or `nslookup` to resolve it?  Or, can whatever client tool you're using directly accept the ELB's DNS name?

Comment: You could use simple `ping a609dda14861b4a477883069eeec1c29-1006084812.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com` to get the (current) IP-Address. But be aware, the IP-Address may change at any time, that's the reason why you should **not** use it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the reason why you need IP instead of DNS?

[Assigning Static IP Address to AWS Load Balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313134/assigning-static-ip-address-to-aws-load-balancer)

Amazon does load balancing by scaling up and down interfaces as needed to handle the request load. That's why it assigns you a domain name instead of an IP address since your load balancer could have multiple physical interfaces, and the IP addresses will frequently change. So it's an obvious anti-pattern to use IP instead of DNS for ELB until you understand the risk or try to achieve something specific.

Comment: I need the IP so that I can whitelist it in my mongodb Atlass database, which the cluster needs to connect with.